# Rails helpers, concatenation

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, concatenation

The problem is the following meaning to use a container wich I give a background image and I also intend it to be a link to the project (for I am making a portfolio).

```
<% if project.has_photo? %>
    <div class="img_container" style="background-image:(/photo_store/<%=project.id%>.<%=project.extension%>);,link_to "http://www.asite.com/"></div>
<%else%>
    <p> theres nothing here #<%=project.id%></p>
<%end%>
```

This doesn't gives any errors however, it doesn't reach the image as you can see, I set and if so it tells me if there is no image, but it does seem to have an image, so I don't really know what's holding it back from displaying it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
<% if project.has_photo? %>
   <%= link_to("example_url") do %>
       <div class="img_container" style="background-image: url(/photo_store/<%=project.id%>.<%=project.extension%>)"></div>
   <% end %>
<%else%>
    <p> theres nothing here </p>
<%end%>
```